# Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "value" in class "Ljava/lang/Integer;" or its superclasses Android 10

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have received a .so android library from a client and I have to integrate that in my Xamarin Forms project. The library helps the app connect to an IoT device. As the library methods are of the following signature, I decided to write a java wrapper to simplify the parameters and create an aar file. Afterwards, I natively bind the aar and use it as a dll in my project.

It is important to note that the problem in Xamarin only occurs when the Compile Target is > 10. Otherwise, it works fine. My guess is that the [latest Updates to non-SDK interfaces broke the application](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q).

Library header:

```
public static native int ReadParams(String token, StringBuilder serial, StringBuilder ssid, StringBuilder password, StringBuilder sensor, Integer keepAlive);
```

The problem:
The method works fine when called from within a native android application however crashes with the following error from Xamarin Forms. The crash is on the following line in the Java wrapper.

Crash line:

```
StringBuilder strSerial = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strssid = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strpassword = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strsensor = new StringBuilder();
Integer keepAlive = new Integer(0);
//Crash on below line
int response = EPM002Lib.ReadParams(token, strSerial, strssid, strpassword, strsensor, keepAlive);
```

The stacktrace:

> --- End of managed Java.Lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError stack trace --- java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "value" in class "Ljava/lang/Integer;" or its superclasses at
> com.esong.lib.EPM002Lib.ReadParams(Native Method) at
> com.sensorwa.config.configdemo.SquareSdkhelper.ReadParams(SquareSdkhelper.java:32)

I understand that more information regarding the internal functionality of the EPM002Lib.ReadParams params would help, however, the library seems to work with a native android application (even when compiled against Android 10). Please feel free to ask for more information or provide suggestions. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why would the library need to access the `int` field anyway? That sounds broken. `Integer`s are supposed to be immutable, so the library mustn't attempt to modify the value. And if they just wanted to read the value, they should use the `intValue` method.

Comment: Yes, I understand. However, I am just curious as to how does it work on native android :/

Comment: Well, it's not clear exactly what you mean by _"compiled against Android 10"_. If you're referring to `compileSdkVersion`, then that's not really relevant here. What matters is the `targetSdkVersion` (and of course the actual Android version that you run the app on).

Comment: Yes, it is compileSdkVersion indeed and I think that its relevant hence the changes to non-sdk interfaces were introduced in sdk 10. From what I understand, targetSdkVersion is the version the app targets, perhaps the one with most users base.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the role of `compileSdkVersion`; it only determines which APIs are available to you at compile-time. The `targetSdkVersion` is what matters when it comes to determining how these kinds of runtime behavior changes are applied. The page you linked to in your question even says so: _"these interfaces belong to the `max-target-p` (`greylist-max-p`) list, so your app can only use these interfaces if it **targets** Android 9 (API level 28) or lower"_.

Comment: As established, you cannot use this library without modification. Thus, what are your degrees of freedom? Are you allowed (license-wise) and able (skill-wise) to modify the library, either in source or the binary?

Comment: @Michael aha I understand. This is problematic as, as of November, Google requires apps to target Android 10 or above.

Comment: @Botje seems like it. I do not have the source to the library. I am (license-wise) allowed to make changes. and skill-wise I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction towards modifying the binary (.so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled this file using the Android Aarch64 compiler:

```
#include <jni.h>

int access_field(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass cls_Integer = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    jfieldID fid_Integer_value = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls_Integer, "value", "I");
    return (*env)->GetIntField(env, obj, fid_Integer_value);
}

int access_method(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass cls_Integer = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Ljava/lang/Integer;");
    jmethodID mid_Integer_value = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_Integer, "intValue", "()I");
    return (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, mid_Integer_value);
}
```

which results in the following code for `access_field`:

```
int access_field(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   0:   d10103ff    sub sp, sp, #0x40
   4:   a9037bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp,#48]
   8:   9100c3fd    add x29, sp, #0x30
   c:   90000008    adrp    x8, 0 <access_field>
  10:   91000108    add x8, x8, #0x0
  14:   90000002    adrp    x2, 0 <access_field>
  18:   91000042    add x2, x2, #0x0
  1c:   90000003    adrp    x3, 0 <access_field>
  20:   91000063    add x3, x3, #0x0
  24:   f81f83a0    stur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  28:   f81f03a1    stur    x1, [x29,#-16]
    jclass cls_Integer = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Ljava/lang/Integer;");
  2c:   f85f83a9    ldur    x9, [x29,#-8]
  30:   f9400129    ldr x9, [x9]
  34:   f9401929    ldr x9, [x9,#48]
  38:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  3c:   aa0803e1    mov x1, x8
  40:   f90007e2    str x2, [sp,#8]
  44:   f90003e3    str x3, [sp]
  48:   d63f0120    blr x9
  4c:   f9000fe0    str x0, [sp,#24]
    jfieldID fid_Integer_value = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls_Integer, "value", "I");
  50:   f85f83a8    ldur    x8, [x29,#-8]
  54:   f9400108    ldr x8, [x8]
  58:   f9417908    ldr x8, [x8,#752]
  5c:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  60:   f9400fe1    ldr x1, [sp,#24]
  64:   f94007e2    ldr x2, [sp,#8]
  68:   f94003e3    ldr x3, [sp]
  6c:   d63f0100    blr x8
  70:   f9000be0    str x0, [sp,#16]
    return (*env)->GetIntField(env, obj, fid_Integer_value);
  74:   f85f83a8    ldur    x8, [x29,#-8]
  78:   f9400108    ldr x8, [x8]
  7c:   f9419108    ldr x8, [x8,#800]
  80:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  84:   f85f03a1    ldur    x1, [x29,#-16]
  88:   f9400be2    ldr x2, [sp,#16]
  8c:   d63f0100    blr x8
  90:   a9437bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp,#48]
  94:   910103ff    add sp, sp, #0x40
  98:   d65f03c0    ret


}
```

and for `access_method`:

```
int access_method(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
  9c:   d10103ff    sub sp, sp, #0x40
  a0:   a9037bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp,#48]
  a4:   9100c3fd    add x29, sp, #0x30
  a8:   90000008    adrp    x8, 0 <access_field>
  ac:   91000108    add x8, x8, #0x0
  b0:   90000002    adrp    x2, 0 <access_field>
  b4:   91000042    add x2, x2, #0x0
  b8:   90000003    adrp    x3, 0 <access_field>
  bc:   91000063    add x3, x3, #0x0
  c0:   f81f83a0    stur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  c4:   f81f03a1    stur    x1, [x29,#-16]
    jclass cls_Integer = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Ljava/lang/Integer;");
  c8:   f85f83a9    ldur    x9, [x29,#-8]
  cc:   f9400129    ldr x9, [x9]
  d0:   f9401929    ldr x9, [x9,#48]
  d4:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  d8:   aa0803e1    mov x1, x8
  dc:   f90007e2    str x2, [sp,#8]
  e0:   f90003e3    str x3, [sp]
  e4:   d63f0120    blr x9
  e8:   f9000fe0    str x0, [sp,#24]
    jmethodID mid_Integer_value = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls_Integer, "intValue", "()I");
  ec:   f85f83a8    ldur    x8, [x29,#-8]
  f0:   f9400108    ldr x8, [x8]
  f4:   f9408508    ldr x8, [x8,#264]
  f8:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
  fc:   f9400fe1    ldr x1, [sp,#24]
 100:   f94007e2    ldr x2, [sp,#8]
 104:   f94003e3    ldr x3, [sp]
 108:   d63f0100    blr x8
 10c:   f9000be0    str x0, [sp,#16]
    return (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, mid_Integer_value);
 110:   f85f83a8    ldur    x8, [x29,#-8]
 114:   f9400108    ldr x8, [x8]
 118:   f940c508    ldr x8, [x8,#392]
 11c:   f85f83a0    ldur    x0, [x29,#-8]
 120:   f85f03a1    ldur    x1, [x29,#-16]
 124:   f9400be2    ldr x2, [sp,#16]
 128:   d63f0100    blr x8
 12c:   a9437bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp,#48]
 130:   910103ff    add sp, sp, #0x40
 134:   d65f03c0    ret
```

The main differences are the offsets used in the `ldr x8` calls. These are offsets into the function pointer table inside the `JNIEnv`, more specifically:

- `GetFieldID` is at offset 752
- `GetIntField` is at offset 800
- `GetMethodID` is at offset 264
- `CallIntMethod` is at offset 392.

The other difference is the signature passed to the `GetIntField` or `GetMethodID`, which is injected at linker time. The object file I dumped is not linked yet, so there are dummy instructions there. It is the fourth argument so it is passed in register `x3`.

So, to summarize, you need to do the following:

- Find the address of the string `"()I"` somewhere in the library or add it to the string table.
- You need to find all places where `java.lang.Integer#value` is accessed.
- Replace the two function pointer offsets (752 -> 264; 800 -> 392) in the `ldr x8` right before the `blr x8` call.
- Find the code that changes `x3` and make it point to `"()I"` instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I will try to implement this in a week :)

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on an implementation detail that was not supposed to be relied on.

Now it broke and you get to keep both pieces.

Comment: There is no magic bullet, you will have to change that library like your linked site states. Google has been warning about this for years.